# Headers sent already before any output with PHP, Nginx on Azure

Tags: php, azure, nginx, http-headers, azure-webapps

I have two hosting environments, one is running PHP 7.4 with Apache, and the other one is running PHP 8.1 with Nginx both on Azure.

I run this PHP script on both:

```
<?php ini_set("display_errors", 1); header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', true, 301); ?>
```

When I run this code on host 1, I get what I expect; the headers are output as 301:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot>curl -is test.php
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2022 08:46:09 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.30
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Running the same script om the Nginx environement under PHP 8.1 I get:

```
root:/home# curl -is localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.22.1
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2022 08:45:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.9

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/site/wwwroot/index.php:1) in <b>/home/site/wwwroot/index.php</b> on line <b>1</b><br />
```

As you can see the header 301 could not be sent because the 200 header was already sent.

There is absolutely nothing before the first *<?php*-tag.

I have tried lots of things with the Nginx config, but no result. Is this something that is inside PHP.INI?

What is causing the header 200 to be sent before any line of my PHP script?

Comment: _"There is absolutely nothing before the first <?php-tag."_ - nothing you directly _see_ perhaps, but there might still be a BOM or something.

Comment: _"s this something that is inside PHP.INI?"_ - output buffering could be turned on by the default on the system where it _is_ working. (But turning it on on the other one as well, isn't really the _solution_.)

Comment: CBroe: the script is the same on both systems. I get no error on the first system.

Comment: _"I get no error on the first system"_ - and I just said what a possible reason for that could be.

Comment: CBroe: output_buffering = on solved my problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: output_buffering is apparently disabled by default, you can turn it on in the INI of PHP, like so:

- Create a folder inside /home/site called ini
- Add a file there with the extention .ini, like site.ini
- Add this line and save:

  output_buffering = on
- Go to your azure portal to the webapp and inside Configuration add an application setting with name = PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR and value = /usr/local/etc/php/conf:/home/site/ini
- Then save the application setting witch will restart your app.